# React js map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

Hi i have the following component called project list

```
const ProjectList = ({projects}) =>{ 
    console.log({projects})
    return(
        <div>
                <h1>Nothing to do</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
export default ProjectList;
```

The  prop {projects} is receiving this:

[image]

When i tried to map the object i got an error mesagge called "projects.map is not a function

```
const ProjectList = ({projects}) =>{ 
    console.log({projects})
    return(
        <div>
         {projects && projects.map (project => { 
            return (
                <ProjectSummary project={project} key={project.id}></ProjectSummary>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

And triying to debug, the {projects} object is empty now:

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting object projects from? what happens if you only console log code where it works, does it console.log twice one with value and other empty ?

Comment: Seems like you project is an object which has 'project' of type array.  You need to  call project.project.map() or better refactor your prop value to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start would be to try logging `Array.isArray(projects)`, it appears in your second screenshot projects is being returned as an Object. As you know, .map is an Array prototype.

To iterate key:value pairs in an Object, you could try (something like):

```
const projectKeys = Object.keys(projects)
projectKeys.map(key => { return projects[key] });
```

Comment: Well thanks but, i still dont get it: i am sorry am kind of new and even surprises me how far i have gone though I still can't  do it; i dont know how to explain you my problem and i dont know where can i explain this in detail; do you mind if you can keep helping me with this?

Comment: it looks like your projects parameter returns:
```
projects: { projects: [] }
```

you may want to try iterating over projects.projects. Hope this helps
sounds like your array exists in projects.projects

Comment: do not worry, i figure it out at the end; i was retriving data from firestore, and i was having 3 promises, the first two were empty  and the last one has all the data. So i simply validate whether or no there was data and done